# set an implicit timeout on webdriver.get(url)

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, settimeout

I'm having some issues on my page load, as the page loads some **asynchronous** stuff, 
I would like to **interrupt** the page load to proceed with the next steps of my test.

1- The **driver.get(url)** this throws **timeoutException after 1800 sec** loading.

2- I have added 
**driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TEST_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);**
it didn't change anything.

I did **driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(time, unit)**
**no change too**

3- The last try was the following
**JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("return window.stop()");** this didn't work

How can I solve this?

Comment: have you tried just completely disabling async requests?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the page load timeout?

```
driver.manage().timeouts().setPageLoadTimeout(time, unit);
```

This should throw the `TimeoutException` when the timeout expires, which you can catch and move on to the next operation. Caveats (may not be implemented in all browsers, behavior might differ) apply.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**
Below solution might resolve your problem of wait. Lets try !

```
static void waitForPageLoad(WebDriver wdriver) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wdriver, 60);

    Predicate<WebDriver> pageLoaded = new Predicate<WebDriver>() {

        @Override
        public boolean apply(WebDriver input) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) input).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }

    };
    wait.until(pageLoaded);
}
```